# How do I get the OR operator to work in this JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been wrestling with this issue off and on for a couple of months now.  Is there away to apply the **"OR" operator** in to this array structure below?

Basics:  If the value in a dropdown matches the value(s) in the array, then the corresponding ID is sent to a function and it does some other stuff, but I have not been able to add/include the **OR operator**.

For example I want to be able to say in the code:

```
{id : '418', value: 'Brochure' || 'Broc'},
{id : '546', value: 'Classified Ad' || 'CA' || 'Class Ad'},
```

But the above never works, so I don't know if it just can't be done or I have the syntax wrong.

Any insight would be appreciated greatly.

---

**Function that is run once value is found**

```
var projectTypes = [{
    "id": "418",
    "value": ["Brochure", "Broc"]
  }, {
    "id": "546",
    "value": ["Classified Ad", "CA", "Class Ad"]
  }, {
    "id": "254",
    "value": ["Flyer", "Flyers"]
  }, {
    "id": "855",
    "value": "Post Card"
  }];

function projectTypeChange() {
    var project_type = document.getElementById(projectType_Field_Id).value;
    SwitchBox(project_type);
}

function SwitchBox(selectedType) {
    for (var i = 0; i < projectTypes.length; i++) {
        if (projectTypes[i].value.indexOf(projectTypes) >= 0)
        //if (projectTypes[i].value == selectedType)
        {
            document.getElementById("section-" + projectTypes[i].id).style.display = '';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("section-" + projectTypes[i].id).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, just have `{id : '418', value: 'Brochure'}` and `{id : '418', value: 'Broc'}`.

Comment: Do you want an array of values, `{id : '418', value: ['Brochure', 'Broc']}`? I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi arxanas.  This option won't work because the funtion which I included above, turns fieldsets on and off as needed, so when the code hits 'Brochure', it will display the fieldset on, but then turn it off when it hits 'Broc'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what Justin suggested. Change this line in your indexof code:

```
if(projectTypes[i].value.indexOf(projectTypes) >= 0)
```

to this:

```
if(projectTypes[i].value.indexOf(selectedType) >= 0)
```

Comment: Oh my word.  I knew I was doing something wrong, I did not realize it was that silly - thank you so much - works like a charm!!!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying to use the || operator (which is incorrect in this case), make the value its own array:

```
{ id: '418', value: ['Brochure','Broc'] },
{ id: '546', value: ['Classified Ad','CA','Class Ad'] }
```

Then instead of checking for equality against value, check indexOf to see if the value is in the array:

```
if(value.indexOf(someVal) >= 0)
{
    // someVal was found in the value array...do the work!
}
```

Comment: Justin Niessner, I added the function that is run against the array.  Could you look above, are you saying to add your code above {the if statement} in place of my if statement (`if (projectTypes[i].value == selectedType`)?

Comment: I added the indexOf function, but I think, well I know, I am doing something wrong.  See the updated code above.  When I run it, it just bypasses the selections in the array, I don't get an error, but the fieldsets do not turn on/off as they should.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: No, it's `.indexOf(selectedType)`, not `projectTypes`

Comment: Oh my word.  I knew I was doing something wrong, I did not realize it was that silly - thank you so much - works like a charm!!!